# Solve $K, L$ from 2 equations in terms of $p$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, economics

Denote $p=$ Price, $K=$ Number of robots, $L=$ Labour

> $$\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{3}pK^{-2/3}L^{1/3}= 2,\\  \\
> \dfrac{1}{3}pK^{1/3}L^{-2/3}= 1.\end{cases}$$

Solve the above for $K$ and $L$.

The above two equations are the partial derivates of the product function:

$$f(K,L) = K^{1/3} L^{1/3}$$

It's a profit maximising exercise and I need to obtain the amount of inputs the firm hires. The answer is in the textbook but I just can't figure how they came up with it:

> $$(K^{\ast},L^{\ast}) = (p^3/108 , p^3/54).$$

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cube both equations, getting ones that are in $K^2L$ and $KL^2$.  Divide them to get one in $\frac KL$ and multiply them and cube root to get one in $KL$.  Multiply those to get one in $K^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but can you just walk me through it step by step? I cube each side to get 1/27pK^-2L=8  and 1/27pKL^-2=1 right? and then what do I do from there exactly? Thanks again champion

Comment: Now multiply them and you will find $K^3L^3$.  Take a cube root to get $KL$.  Divide the two you have to get $K/L$  Multiply those two to eliminate $L$ and get $K^2$

Comment: Mate when I cube both sides, the power of K is negative 2 and L is negative 2? (-2/3)^3 = - 2

Comment: I thought the exponent on $K$ in the second was $-1/3$ not $1/3$.  You are effectively solving simultaneous equations in two variables, but trying to get rid of the exponents.  Back to the first comment, square the first and multiply by the second to eliminate $L$.